# Pytorch import error in Jupyter notebook in Windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook, importerror, torch

I installed torch 1.5.1 using conda install with CUDA 10.2. I was able to install it successfully. While importing torch in Jupyter, I am getting below error.

*OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "c:\users\shashank\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2.dll" or one of its dependencies.*